# How to make my own XML layout view from other views

Tags: android, android-layout

I have one `RelativeLayout` that has `TextView` (first label) , `EditText`(for input), `TextView` (second label). I have this in at least 10 activities in my project. How I can extract view and make my own. So, if I want to change *textSize* , I will have to change it on just one place, not 10.

For example I would like to have this

```
<RelativeLayout
  android:width="match_parent"
  android:height="wrap_content"
>
  <TextView
    android:id="firstTextView"
    ...
    android:text="I like">
  <EditText
     android:id="edittextColor" 
     hint="type some color here"
     ... >
<TextView
    android:id="secondTextView"
    ...
    android:text="car.">
    </RelativeLayout>
```

So, I need something like this on a lot of place. What I would like to have is:

```
<MySpecialView
   firstText="I like"
   colorEditTextHint="type color here"
   secondText="car"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Inflaters**

Let's suppose that your **`RelativeLayout`** file is called `reusable_layout`. This means that you could access it as `R.layout.reusable_layout` (considering that you have this file stored in the layouts folder of your project).

In your usual override of **`onCreate()`** add these variables at the start: `LayoutInflater inflater = getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
RelativeLayout layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.reusable_layout, null);`

Afterwards, call `setContentView(layout);`

If you want to edit the children you can call `layout.getChildAt(int childNumber);` This would return you a **`View`**

An example of editing the first `TextView` child:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) layout.getChildAt(0);
tv.setText("Example String");
```

**UPDATE:**
**Another way to do what you want!**

Creating a custom view may do the job!

**A good tutorial on these is included here: https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html#subclassview**

I think all you need to know is included in that.
Another possibly useful source would be included here: [how to add views inside a custom View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6331740/how-to-add-views-inside-a-custom-view)

**Hope I helped,**

**-Daniel**

Comment: Thanks. I knew this but I still need it as Xml

Comment: I'm glad but why would you need it in XML? You still must do setContentView() when the Activity is created right? Thus it would make no difference. I have an idea on how to do what you have asked for and am researching it.

Comment: I need it because of better organization of xml files. I will update question

Comment: I have edited my answer, it, I hope, will answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can create one common layout and include in all the 10 activities layout like this

**common_layout.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">


  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/label1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Label1"/>

  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/input1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/label1"
    android:text="Input1"/>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

**activity_layout**

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <LinearLayout 
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:orientation="vertical"  
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include layout="@layout/common_layout"/>

        <TextView
          android:id="@+id/textinactivity_tv"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Activity text"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

I hope this is what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

> Although Android offers a variety of widgets to provide small and
>   re-usable interactive elements, you might also need to re-use larger
>   components that require a special layout. To efficiently re-use
>   complete layouts, you can use the **include** and **merge** tags to
>   embed another layout inside the current layout.
>   https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html

What about `<include>`
create you `your_base_layout.xml` and `<include>` it in any other xml in the place where you want to add it

your_base_layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:id="@+id/some_other_id">
   <Button
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/button1" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

---

```
<include
   android:id="@+id/include_id"
   layout="@layout/your_base_layout" />
```

example of usage: another_layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/app_bg"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

      <include
         android:id="@+id/include_id"
         layout="@layout/your_base_layout" />

    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="@string/hello"
              android:padding="10dp" />

    ...

</LinearLayout>
```

This is how you access views in it,

```
View includedLayout = findViewById(R.id.some_id_if_needed);
Button buttonInsideTheIncludedLayout = (Button) includedLayout.findViewById(R.id.button1); // if there is a button in your base layout that you included access like this
```

find great answers >[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8834898/what-is-the-purpose-of-androids-merge-tag-in-xml-layouts)

Comment: What if I want to change first label text and make it different for each of them?

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own control with specified attributes.

Save ButtonPlus.java into your package.

e.g.

```
public class ButtonPlus extends Button {

    public ButtonPlus(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ButtonPlus(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        CustomFontHelper.setCustomFont(this, context, attrs);
    }

    public ButtonPlus(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        CustomFontHelper.setCustomFont(this, context, attrs);
    }
}
```

And you can use  inside your layout XML file.